# gumtree like email communication system

Tags: php, database, email, encryption, communication

looking for some pointers on how to develop a buyer/seller email sysem like Gumtree's, ie the seller will get an email from the buyer but the email is sent from gumtree's domain and when the seller replies it is sent to the buyers personal email address via gumtree. Nor the buyer or the seller will ever see each other's email address.

PHP is preferred but any language will do just to understand the concept of how it is done.

Comment: Please read the [help] and [ask].  Your question is too broad for StackOverflow's Q&A style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well thnks all. what would one do without google? (yahoo?)

[https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-up-an-email-relay-system-similar-to-craigslist-where-both-parties’-anonymity-is-protected](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-set-up-an-email-relay-system-similar-to-craigslist-where-both-parties%E2%80%99-anonymity-is-protected)